# What is the simplest way to send an email with an attachment using Python?

Tags: python, email, attachment

What is the simplest way to send an email with an mp3 attachment using Python? I've written scripts in the past which used a pipe to sendmail to send basic email messages, but I've never bothered with attachments before.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [email package](http://docs.python.org/library/email-examples.html). It's pretty simple.

In the URL I linked, you'll find straight examples on how to do just that.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Sean W. With very little modification to that example you will also be able to send MP3 files.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at the python code used for: http://caspian.dotconf.net/menu/Software/SendEmail/