# Sending an email with an attachment using subprocess in python

Tags: python

```
import subprocess

def send_message(recipient, subject, body):
    process = subprocess.Popen(['mail', '-s', subject, recipient], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    process.communicate(body)

send_message(recipient, subject, body)
```

Currently using this small script to send a regular message. Is it possible to send an attachment with this email? Would rather not change it up to use smtplib as of now if possible.

Comment: Have you looked at `email` yet?

Comment: Indent your code

Comment: The "standard" way with `mail` I've used in the past is to `cat` together the body of the email with a `uuencode`-ed attachment and then pipe the output into `mail`.

Comment: The `email` package has quite a good load of [relevant examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#email-examples).

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised that there was no answer to this question, or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37141290/python3-subprocess-email-attachment), or that [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5614123/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-send-an-email-with-an-attachment-using-python) suggests using libraries like `email` or `smtp`. Sure, those libraries are great for more complex tasks, but if your task can be achieved with `subprocess` and the `mail` binary it is still the *simplest* way in Python. And adding an attachment *can* be done with this - at least with my version of `mail` (GNU Mailutils 3.7), which came installed on my OS (Ubuntu 20.04.6). The flag might differ slightly, or the feature may not exist, on other versions.

The man page for `MAIL.MAILUTILS(1)` says:

```
-A, --attach=FILE
```

So I modified my script like this:

```
def send_email(subject, recipient, body="", attachment=None):
    """Send an email with optional body, attachment. Recipient can take multiple addresses, comma-separated"""
    mail_process_args = ["mail", f"-s {subject}", recipient]
    if attachment is not None:
        mail_process_args.append(f"-A{attachment}")
    subprocess.run(mail_process_args, input=body.encode(), check=False)
```

Note that I need to check if there is an attachment, since adding a blank string as an attachment will cause a failure.